# Import info from mdb file into a project?

Tags: qgis, data, import, database, ms-access

I need to import info on a QGIS project.

The info are in a MDB file (population, mean age, number of cars and so on: one record per region) that is written to be connected with a region shape from an unique ID (the ID is the same in the MDB and in the QGIS shapefile).

Comment: load as esri personal geodatabase? [.mdb] match by id - or save the mdb as .dbf or csv and load in..

Comment: the info are coming from a database not connected with GIS. I am not able to load my file info.dbf (exported from info.mdb)

Comment: See also: [Can QGIS read an ODBC connection?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/can-qgis-read-an-odbc-connection/73160#73160)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solutions works:

1. / 2. / 3. done (thanks to @Unicoletti reply)
2. add vector and choose your exported file ("info.dbf" in this case)
3. you can see the new layer in the left bar
4. double-click on the original layer ("town") and go in the menu join
5. add a new join choosing the layer "info"
6. choose the colum to match in each file
7. you should have in the original layer the data coming from your DB

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that QGIS 1.8 *on Windows* supports .mdb under Layer->Add Vector Layer...->Browse->and change the file type in the drop-down to the right of the "File name"" form field.

But.... QGIS 1.8 on OSX *does not* support opening of .mdb's (afaict)

Comment: This is now again possible for Mac with the GDAL MDB Java-based driver. See this [homebrew project pull request](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/23229), which also has a [patch file for GDAL 1.10.1 configure script](https://gist.github.com/dakcarto/6877854).

Answer (score 3):

**WARN**: it seems the 'Join Attributes' function ha been removed from fTools 0.6.2, solution for me was to downgrade to 0.6.1.

---

You can use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) to perform the operation you want, please proceed as follows:

1. if not installed already, install Quantum GIS (an Open Source desktop GIS) and then install fTools as described [here](http://www.ftools.ca/install.html)
2. export the mdb table or query into dbf format (from Access, select the object, right click, export)
3. open the region shapefile in qgis
4. click on the Vector menu, Data management, Join attributes (I am translating roughly from my localized version)
5. fill out the dialog and then click ok
6. you should now have another layer with data from btoh the region shapefile and the dbf file

See the image below for an example:

[image: Usage example]

Comment: 1. done (QGIS v1.7.4) 2. done 3. done (the existing shape eg. "Town.shp", without my info) 4. done 5. is asks: "vector output" and "join vector" but I cannot find my file "info.dbf". I think "output shapefile" is the name of my new shape

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: my Vector menu/Data Managment is a bit different (Qgis 1.7.4) and I am not able to find the new layer coming from info.dbf