# How to connect QGIS with Access database

Tags: qgis-2.4, ms-access, connection

I am trying to connect Access database with QGIS like I would in ArcView but I get this problem.

[image: data source name not found]

`Data source name not found and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect`

Hoping someone can help.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/can-qgis-read-an-odbc-connection

Comment: And a comment on the accepted answer in the question Jakob links to leads to another question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115584 Not sure if this would end up being a duplicate of one or the other, though I would lean toward the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I found this if it can help you:

http://www.geoinformations.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/fichier/pdf/Connexion_a_une_BD_Access_dans_QGis_2_sous_Windows_7_cle73515a.pdf?arg=177833518&cle=99520bea1e99654939fbc1f8a2db965e9776e46a&file=pdf%2FConnexion_a_une_BD_Access_dans_QGis_2_sous_Windows_7_cle73515a.pdf