# Unable to establish a persistent ODBC connection to an access mdb database

Tags: qgis, odbc

I’m an MS Access diehard and I’m running a 64bit version of Win 10 on my PC. I’ve installed both the 32bit (2.14.7) and 64bit (2.16.3) versions of QGIS on it, and MS Office 2016.  I would like to establish a persistent ODBC connection to an access mdb database but can’t get this to work on either on versions of QGIS.

Using the EVis plugin I have no issues in terms of linking to mdb, and identically accdb, databases on both the 32bit and 64bit versions of QGIS.  However, try as I may I can’t form a successful link via QGIS’s add vector layer ‘database’, ‘ODBC’ setting – the only thing I get is a database table header, its field structure, but no data whatsoever and the name assigned to the layer when I attempt this ends with ‘Unknown’.

[image]

It has been suggested that a modification to QGIS's bat file should overcome the issue I'm experiencing, as per adding the following two lines:

`set OGR_SKIP=ODBC
set PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE=DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=%%s`

I've done this, but in my two installations of QGIS the second line of that code doesn't appear to have any effect, since when I drag an mdb file into QGIS's workspace I get an invalid file format error.

How I can resolve this issue and establish in QGIS a persistent ODBC connection to an access mdb database?

Comment: Can you try my ODBC/vrt solution from http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115584/qgis-2-4-access-mdb-add-error ? It works for me with 32-bit QGIS and MS Access.