# Open .mdb files in QGIS 2.14.1

Tags: qgis, ms-access

I Use QGIS ver 2.14.1

I've got a little problem here
I already following how to open mdb at link below :

[QGIS 2.4 access .mdb add error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115584/qgis-2-4-access-mdb-add-error)

But error dialog box always pop out when I click "OK" (after I Create connection and test it)
It said "Connection Failed - Check settings and try again."
"Extended error information : ORA-12541: TNS no listener in "

Why error dialog box always pop out when I test the connection ?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358656/oracle-client-ora-12541-tnsno-listener and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73944/ora-12541-tnsno-listener . I wonder why you get an Oracle error message.

Comment: I have no Idea.. I just following the step and error message come out.. @AndreJ

Comment: I guess you have `Database` still set to `Oracle Spatial` where it should be switched to `ODBC`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QGIS 2.4 access .mdb add error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115584/qgis-2-4-access-mdb-add-error)