# Adding "monitor" layer with Access Database and coordinates x/y in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, coordinates, latitude-longitude, ms-access

I want to add a Microsoft Access "mdb" or "accdb" as vector layer.
The layer should work all the time with current updated data from the Access file. This function allready exist for a txt(!) file:
Layer>add Layer>add txt file as layer. Also hit checkbox for "keep watching file" for current data.
Maybe there is an accdb third party plugin

Also known function:
Database>Evis only create a momentary connection and is not my solution. Finally I want probably the same like the txt as vector layer.
My problem is to tell QGIS the X and Y collumns (for ex. longitude/latitude coordinates) and I haven't found any way still there.

Comment: Why would it be surprising that it exists for ubqiuitous text files and not a proprietary .mdb/.accdb, especially given that MS Access is not available in basic distributions of office? That aside, I suspect a workaround would be to create a server to serve the data from the database and connect to the server in QGIS. When adding data from text files it is possible to specify which columns to use for geometry and the format that the geometry is in.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your message. Is it possible to join the Database via "Evis" connection not only temporary but also fix with every QGIS Launch? Seems to be your named solution, right? The Access file is already laying on a Server. Or do you mean converting Access to txt on a Server and join the new created txt to qgis? ...I do not create a txt after every data Input Change in the Access :-/

Comment: This answer might help [http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115713/64402](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115713/64402) - although, I'm hoping that if using an accdb you can stick with 64bit. My comment on the server was that rather than trying to access the .mdb/.accdb directly, you connect to it via ODBC or other data connection as appropriate, which is what the linked answer suggests.

Comment: I added an answer to the linked question using a vrt file to handle the geometry columns correctly. But you may need a 32bit QGIS for that. HTH

Comment: Thank you Andre for your time. I'll have a look on it  :-)