# QGIS error when open project when layer via accesses the database

Tags: qgis, database

I changed from QGIS 1.7.3 to 1.8.0. Problem is that I can´t open QGIS Projects, QGIS crashes when there are layers involved loaded via access-database connection. I used eVis.
What can I do?

Comment: Could you solve the problem with the non static MS-access connection? I have a similar problem with 1.7.1. I create a project with the connection to access. But when i save and close the project and start again there open a window calls "Defekte Layer behandeln"

Comment: As I wrote above, it is only possible if you save the temporary file to another folder before closing Qgis, and copying it back to the original place. It may be solved in Qgis 2.0.0 ...

Answer (score 2):

If its not a big project (not a lot of layers), consider starting from scratch?

Comment: Good idea. Just open a new database connection, load a layer and save it under a different project name.  Maybe that is already enough to reuse the old .qgis files. Otherwise you can compare the .qgis files in a text editor. Look for the <datasource> tags.

Comment: O.k. I tried but it still don´t work. I opened the project-file with edito and found following (see below) what is something wrong with it?      
<id>xy_Standorte20120831084035124</id>
            <datasource>file://C:/Users/oppia04/AppData/Local/Temp/qt_temp.ae5956?delimiter=%09&amp;delimiterType=regexp&amp;xField=GK3%20x%20coordinate&amp;yField=GK3%20y%20coordinate</datasource>

Comment: Nothing "wrong" so far. Is this the old (1.7.4) or the new (1.8.0) project file? You have to compare both. The problem is that the database is not written in here, instead a path to a temporary file. The new Qgis will open a different temporary file. You can exchange the path with a text editor if you know the new one.

Comment: my directory is "c:/Benutzer/oppia04" instead of "c:/users.." because of the german system but it becomes spooky..
There is no temp-file saved in this direction. When I create the connection I can see one the temp-file "hq_temp.hp1240" in the right direction (i.e. c:/benutzer...temp) after saving, closing and opening qgis it is gone. And the spooky thing is that after one trial it works, I created a connection saved it and there are two files "qt_temp.gq5544" and "qt_temp_hp5544"
so the problem is with loading old files and the same when I create them with 1.8.0.
Thank you for help!!

Comment: For the first part: You see "C:\Benutzer" in Windows 7 Explorer, but it is "C:\user" on commandline level. I will make a test for myself over the weekend. Its no problem that the temp file is gone, it only should reappear next time with the same name.

Comment: oh, thats true, command line is correct. my settings. I used evis database connection, type MS access..thank you!!

Comment: one more info, I connected the database and copied the temp-file with different name. When I restart qgis it crushed like before. When rename the saved temp file in the right direction everything works.
For the old files it would be good to know what part of the script I could delete in the editor to hinder the access on the file?

Comment: I have tested now on Windoes 7 with Qgis 1.7.4 and 1.8.0, but did not get managed to reopen a project even with the same version. Reading http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/can-qgis-read-an-odbc-connection (last answer) I'm afraid evis only serves as a database importer, and the data is gone when closing the program. Only solution I see is to export the data to a shapefile or spatialite database immediately, and remove the access database layer before quitting.

Comment: Thank you Andre!
Is it possible to delete the respective commands out of the script via editor? From where to where?

Comment: Just tested something else: If I save the temporary file before closing, and moving it back to the temp folder, the project reopens. Even if I close again, the file remains. But that is not a live connection to the database anymore. There is a ticket for this bug: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6119

Comment: Yes, thats true and what happens by accident. 
For restarting older version projects the problem was when the file was: <datasource> file:///E:..
when I delete those and remain those <datasource> E:.. everythng works like it should...