# Microsoft Access mdb "is not a valid or recognized data source" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ms-access, odbc

The answer to RyanDalton's question ["Can QGIS read an ODBC connection?"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/can-qgis-read-an-odbc-connection/73160#73160) explains how to establish a link in QGIS with an MS-Access table. Following his steps, I can establish an ODBC link (I successfully complete up to step 7), but when the .mdb is imported, I get an error that the file "is not a valid or recognized data source" in QGIS. I assumed QGIS would read each table as a non-spatial layer, as mentioned in the OGR_OGBC [specs](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_odbc.html), but this is not happening. Can anyone tell me why the tables are not being read? Thanks in advance. I am using a 64-bit version of Windows with 32-bit QGIS and OGDB drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables are not being read because the user permissions (I believe for Admin) were not turned on inside the MS-Access DB. I turned them on for all the tables and QGIS loaded the tables (albeit somewhat slowly).

Comment: Please go ahead and check the "Accepted" checkmark next to your answer in a day or two (when the rules state it is ok).  This will "close" this question out.  Thanks, and glad you discovered the answer to your problem!