# Open mdb database (created in ArcGIS10) in QGIS 2.2/2.4

Tags: qgis-2.4, geotiff-tiff, personal-geodatabase, qgis-2.2

I have a bunch of orthophotomaps (about 250 tiff files) organized in 3 mdb databases created in ArcGIS10.
I'm now trying to open the mdb files one by one in Qgis 2.2 and 2.4 (Layer->Add vector layer->Browse->Open) but I cannot browse within the database to select the table to import. I can just select the mdb file and I keep getting the same error message "Invalid Data Source: E:\Orthophotos\Block 3\block3.mdb is not a valid or recognized data source".

I know several questions have been asked already on this matter but none of the solution suggested helps me to solve this problem.

Does anyone know how to handle the issue? If QGIS is not able to open such files, I'm available to start from scratch (i.e. from the tiff files) but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Hi Ivan, you mentioned you checked several questions but it's useful to list them as it stops others from having to direct them to you. You can always edit your question by clicked the **edit** button below the tags or you can click [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/127266/edit). In light of this, have you already checked this [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115584/qgis-2-4-access-mdb-add-error) and this [one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85514/microsoft-access-mdb-is-not-a-valid-or-recognized-data-source-in-qgis)?