# Displaying geometry points from database layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have an Access Database with a table of Lats and Longs (as well as other attributes).

I can create a layer using an ODBC connection and can open the attribute table etc but can't figure out how to display the points on the screen.

I could create a shapefile of the points separately and link this to the Access file but would prefer not to have to do this.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Just found the answer using the processing toolbox from the link below and it works well.

[Can QGIS read an ODBC connection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/can-qgis-read-an-odbc-connection?rq=1)